# How to watch movies in Black and White ? ( no colors )

Tags: windows, windows-vista, media, vlc-media-player

Where I can change settings to watch movie in black and white in VLC  ?

if this feature is available on any other player , please let me know .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VLC open Effects and Filters (Ctrl+E), on the Video effects tab, Basic section: slide down the saturation.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version of VLC (1.0.3), do the following:

1. Open the video file/DVD
2. Goto *Tools > Effects and Filters* (Ctrl + E)
3. Goto the *Video Effects* tab, then *Basic*.
4. Check the *Image adjust* box.
5. Drag the *Saturation* slider fully to the left.

You should then have fully black & white (well, actually grayscale) video.

Comment: ...and then how do you export it as a new file????